# Making package of services with user friendly customization options

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I know it looks like just a basic question but it's not. I gave it a thought for a day but couldn't find the exact path to proceed with.
So here is the requirement which I am talking about -

Site will have list of services. From those services some package will be prepared. Like there would be 5 fixed kinds of services, in each kind there can be multiple services are there on site offered by client.
For every kind one default service is selected and will be shown to user but there would be option to choose some other instead of it and the price will change accordingly for the full package.

This same thing is applied on DELL site if you browse. They let us customize a laptop/computer.

Payment is not issue for me now as I can for collecting information and let user submit their basic details for client to contact them.

I have to make this in Drupal 7 & I am wondering which modules can help me in at-least start. Later I can plan for some custom module too once the initial structure is prepared..

Anybody have any suggestion for it then ?

Comment: The only thing I can recommend is http://drupal.org/project/ubercart As far as I know it has configurable products and bundled products.

Comment: I have used ubercart & I still maintain two sites made in D6 with ubercart. I don't have courage to start bundling products using ubercart in D6. First - There is no direct option & second - Its a big pain to do something with ubercart with coding..not much community help too...

Comment: Have you considered using magento? I know you said it isn't an option, but magento has all that by default :) Maybe you can convince the client to change his mind.

Comment: Sorry to say but I can't. I also don't know Magento,so can't think of working with it immediately..

Comment: That's too bad. I can't help you more than this, good look on your future endeavors and may the forces of evil become confused on the way to your house.

Comment: Have to agree with @VladPreda magento would make your life a lot easier. Drupal is great for hacking a site together quickly, but it's a PITA for anything else. Great way to say bye BTW, Vlad. :)

Comment: @Creynders: it's copied from George Carlin. But I use it whenever I get the chance :)

Comment: @VladPreda Ah, George Carlin, may he kick a lot of *ss in the afterlife; love him :)

Comment: @VladPreda - What do you think of http://drupal.org/project/commerce_product_bundle ?

Comment: It's still in alpha version, so tread with care :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are just collecting info I suggest you to use multistep forms and add some jQuery.
Multistep forms are available as content types and also in webforms submissions.
You can redirect your user to the next "service" or form when a choice has been completed using rules. You can relate a node (webform) to a service, and redirect users depending on the submitted info.
Hope that helps!